# Handle exceptions caused by parsing nullable parameters in controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an endpoint

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetNodes([FromQuery] Guid? parentId)
```

And call it like that
`GET .../api/nodes?parentId=null`
Asp.net throws an exception when parsing parameter `"The value 'null' is not valid."`
How to override that behaviour to make it parse nullable types to null if an exception occurs?

I expect:
`GET .../api/nodes?parentId=null` should call action with `parentId == null`

---

`GET .../api/nodes?parentId=50d21ddd-6a95-46db-bff9-c943cf5b0df1` should call action with `parentId = "50d21ddd-6a95-46db-bff9-c943cf5b0df1"`

---

`GET .../api/nodes?parentId=something_not_parsable_to_guid` should call action with `parentId = null`

Comment: what about using a `string` type instead of a `Guid`?

Comment: Null in query string is considered as string and it won't be able to convert to Guid... Using string type is better option.

Comment: @chetanranpariya I don't think that using raw string instead of guid is better option. If I need to make some comparisons with guids I have to create an instance of guid instead of just checking it on null

Comment: @vikscool in string I expect `parentId=null` to be `"null"` and `parentId=` to be `null`

Comment: [HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetNodes([FromQuery] Guid? parentId = null) or [HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetNodes([FromQuery] Guid? =default(Guid))

Comment: @vikscool also I will need to verify that given string is a valid Guid before making any changes

Comment: @delta12 it will fail if I pass something different than a valid guid or empty `=` sign

Comment: You should use url like `.../api/nodes`, no need to append `?parentId=null` when you want to pass it `null`.

Comment: @karan It will make me to rework js-side of the application. I think there is a way to make backend side smarter

Comment: @karan what if I need a route with multiple optional parameters? I don't want to touch anything in javascript code

Comment: I have added answer. Also answer from Anupam Singh is good as well with little different approach. You can use any of it you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just made a simple `IModelBinder` that converts a string into a instance of the desired type if it supports default convertation
code is looking like this:

```
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var targetType = bindingContext.ModelType;
    var targetName = bindingContext.ModelName;
    var stringValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(targetName).FirstValue;

    var isNullableOrReference = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType) != null ||
                                !targetType.IsValueType;

    var valueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(targetName);
    try
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
        var resultValue = converter.ConvertFromString(stringValue);

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(resultValue);
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(targetName, valueProvider);
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException e)
    {
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(isNullableOrReference ? null : Activator.CreateInstance(targetType));
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(targetName, valueProvider);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

It needs to be a bit tuned, but it works as I wanted it to be

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @Karan is the way you should go. But if you are not willing to change your client-side script, you still have the option as follows :

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetNodes() {
     var parentId = Request.QueryString["parentId"].ToString();
     Guid guid;
     if (Guid.TryParse(parentId , out guid))
     {
       // use guid here
     }

}
```

Comment: I have suggested the same.. +1

Comment: But still you need to declare `guid` object first. Or if C# 7 or above is used then we can define as `if (Guid.TryParse(parentId , out Guid guid))`

Answer (score 1):

Convert you `Guid` parameter to `string` and then try with `Guid.TryParse`

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetNodes([FromQuery] string parentId)
{
        Guid guid;
        if (Guid.TryParse(parentId, out guid))
        {
            // code when guid is not null.
            // use guid object.
        }
        else
        {
            // code when guid is null.
        }
}
```